# writing the prefix function (Haskell)

Tags: haskell

I'm writing a prefix function that will take a binary function and a list of numbers as parameters, and returns a list formed by computing the successive function and accumulating as you go.
To make things simple, Here's an example:

```
prefix (+) [2, 4, 1, 1]
  returns [2, 6, 7, 8]

prefix (+) [0, 2, -3, 4, -5]
   returns [0, 2, -1, 3, -2]

prefix max [2, 3, 1, 1]
   returns [2, 3, 3, 3]
```

Here's my code so far however I get an error when i try to load the file because 'list is not in range'. How can i rewrite it so it makes sense to the compiler? Any help will be appreciated.

```
prefix' :: (a -> b) -> [a] ->[b]  
prefix' _ [] = []  
prefix' f (x:xs) 
      | ((list !! x) == 0) = f (list !! 0) (list !! 0)
      | otherwise = prefix' f xs
```

Comment: While the compiler does do some pretty magical stuff, expecting it to know what you mean by `list` just because that's the English name for the type of one of the arguments to your function seems a bit unreasonable. It only knows the names you tell it -- which in this case are `f`, `x`, `xs`, `prefix'`, and whatever is available from the `Prelude`. You'll have to write your implementation in terms of those.

Comment: @DanielWagner do you think everything else in my function is correct though?

Comment: I've never heard of this function called by the name `prefix`? In the standard library, it's called [`scanl1`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:scanl1). A [prefix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefix) is something well-defined, albeit completely different.

Comment: @Chalupa I think there are many errors in your code, potentially stemming from several misunderstandings of Haskell. I suspect you would be best served by finding a buddy who knows Haskell and sitting down with them. People here will try to give you some help, but it's going to be tough going in plain text and without tight interaction with you. You could also consider hopping on #haskell IRC channel, which at least mitigates the "tight interaction" problem.

Comment: prefix' is just what i decided to name it. it does not already exist on its own

Comment: @DanielWagner well i don't have a buddy that knows Haskell, any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
prefix::(a -> a -> a) -> [a] -> [a]
prefix f lst| null lst = []
            | null (tail lst) = lst
            | otherwise = h : prefix' f (f h) (tail lst) where
               h = head lst
            prefix' fn fc (x:xs) | null xs = [acc]
                                 | otherwise = acc : prefix' fn (fn acc) xs where
                                    acc = fc x
```

I will try to explain the above code as much as possible. The type signature of the function is one that takes a function `(a->a->a)` and a list `[a]` as parameter and returns another list with that function applied to each adjacent pair of the list. The `a` in the parameter list simply implies any type (which can be anything). If we had specified a specific type (i.e. in Title case), the function will only work with that specific type

- The function works by first checking if the list it recieved is empty (`null lst`), if so we simply return an empty list
- The next thing it checks for is if the list only contains one item in it (`null (tail lst)`), in that case, we simply return the list
- The third case is when we actually do something, and the first thing we do is to append the first element in the list to head of our new list (`head lst`) and call another function which we have defined on the fly to do compute the rest of the list (`: prefix' f (f (head lst)) (tail lst)`). Note the `:` separates the head from the rest of the list
- The `prefix'` function has a type signature of `(a -> a -> a) -> (a -> a) -> [a] -> [a]` so as you can see the only thing different about it is that it takes one extra parameter which is a function (`fc`) that takes an element of type `a` and returns an element of type `a`. To create this function, we have simply passed one parameter to the initial function recieved as argument which creates this new function. This will be useful in computing the rest of the list
- The base case for this new function is that if the list only contains one element, it applies the new parameter function `fc` to that element in the list and returns a list containing the return value of the function
- Otherwise it will apply `fc` to the first element of the list and we generate `fc` again by applying `fn` to the return value of `fc x`.

If you are interested in learning how all these work, this is the [website](http://learnyouahaskell.com/chapters) I've been using and my knowledge of haskell has improved greatly due to this website, so highly recommended

Comment: i get this error :    Couldn't match type ‘b’ with ‘a -> b’
      ‘b’ is a rigid type variable bound by
          the type signature for prefix :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
          at Hask3.hs:1:9
    Expected type: a -> a -> b
      Actual type: a -> b
    Relevant bindings include
      l :: [a] (bound at Hask3.hs:2:10)
      f :: a -> b (bound at Hask3.hs:2:8)
      prefix :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b] (bound at Hask3.hs:2:1)
    In the first argument of ‘prefix'’, namely ‘f’
    In the second argument of ‘(:)’, namely
      ‘prefix' f (f (head l)) (tail l)’

Comment: Yup, same here, I didn't test yet, I will fix in a moment

Comment: @Chalupa, try that now

Comment: If the purpose is to just get something working, `prefix = scanl1` seems much less baroque. If the purpose is to learn how to write this function in Haskell, the complete lack of discussion makes this answer unenlightening. So what purpose is this answer addressing?

Comment: @DanielWagner, well for one practice for myself (I just started learning haskell a week ago) and two, to provide a code that does what OP is asking. I can't seem to think of any other reason. I don't even know what `scanl1` is or how imports work in haskell, so that's out of the question

Comment: The explanation improves this answer a lot. Thanks for including it!

Answer (score 3):

Isn't what you want to implement the [`scanl1`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/src/GHC-List.html#scanl1) function? I'm a beginner too, but from what I understood, it goes like this:

```
scanl1                  :: (a -> a -> a) -> [a] -> [a]
scanl1 f (x:xs)         =  scanl f x xs
scanl1 _ []             =  []
```

The `scanl` function. which `scanl1` uses, goes like this:

```
scanl                   :: (b -> a -> b) -> b -> [a] -> [b]
scanl                   = scanlGo
  where
    scanlGo           :: (b -> a -> b) -> b -> [a] -> [b]
    scanlGo f q ls    = q : (case ls of
                               []   -> []
                               x:xs -> scanlGo f (f q x) xs)
```

Here's what [hackage](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:scanl) has to say about `scanl`:

```
scanl :: (b -> a -> b) -> b -> [a] -> [b] Source
```

`scanl` is similar to `foldl`, but returns a list of successive reduced values from the left:

```
scanl f z [x1, x2, ...] == [z, z `f` x1, (z `f` x1) `f` x2, ...]
```

Note that

```
last (scanl f z xs) == foldl f z xs.
```

So, I guess the flow of execution goes like this:

```
scanl1 (+) [2, 4, 1, 1]

scanl (+) 2 [4, 1, 1]

scanlGo (+) 2 [4, 1, 1]
2 : scanlGo (+) (+ 2 4) [1, 1]
2 : 6 : scanlGo (+) (+ 6 1] [1]
2 : 6 : 7 : scanlGo (+) (+ 7 1) []
2 : 6 : 7 : 8 : scanlGo []
2 : 6 : 7 : 8 : []
[2, 6, 7, 8]
```

The same thing happens with the `(*)` and the `max` functions that you mentioned. Hope this helps.